# USAEPAY Payment Gateway integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway, usaepay

I am working on integrating USAEPAY with my eCommerce website. I am able to make a payment through Payment form.

I recieve an email saying that the payment was successful with all the information entered by the client. I have selected the response as POST to a URL in my website.

If you notice, most of the fields are empty and I cannot know, what is the amount and the client name and so on. Please let me know if I have missed anything.

Here is the response received when the payment was successful :

```
UMstatus=Approved, 
UMauthCode=TESTMD, 
UMrefNum=0, 
UMavsResult=Address: Match & 5 Digit Zip: Match, 
UMavsResultCode=YYY, 
UMcvv2Result=Match, 
UMcvv2ResultCode=M, 
UMresult=A, 
UMvpasResultCode=, 
UMerror=, 
UMerrorcode=00000, 
UMcustnum=, 
UMbatch=, 
UMbatchRefNum=, 
UMisDuplicate=N, 
UMconvertedAmount=, 
UMconvertedAmountCurrency=840, 
UMconversionRate=, 
UMcustReceiptResult=No Receipt Sent, 
UMprocRefNum=, 
UMcardLevelResult=, 
UMauthAmount=, 
UMresponseHash=s/1424267120.9422973438661/c250f9c99a9a324be1064213b42703ba61620eb0, 
UMinvoice=1234, 
UMinvioce=1234,
```

Answer (score 2):

You should deactivate the test mode for the Source key. For sandbox login at https://sandbox.usaepay.com/console/, go to Settings -> Source Keys, then edit the necessary one, and uncheck the "Test Mode" option.

Sandbox is a test environment by itself, and it's recommended not to use the production environment in a test mode, which is actually deprecated.

help.usaepay.com/developer/testmode

help.usaepay.com/developer/guide/testaccount

Comment: This is the correct answer, select it. It worked for me